# Raspberry Pi freezes when python starts to play

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've written a program in python, on my Mac, which I intend to run on a Raspberry Pi.

It includes a background picture that changes, and a button that starts/stops music playing.

The program uses pygame.

On the Mac it runs exactly as I expect it to do.

But when I run it on the Pi, and the play button is pressed, the whole program freezes for 25 - 30 seconds (the images stop changing, can't ctrl+alt+f to a different login) with no sound. After the freeze the program resumes, sound start playing ....

There's nothing logged in /var/log/syslog ....

In the main object for the program I initialise the mixer.

```
    def __init__(self):
            pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.init()
```

Then the play button in the program calls this method to toggle the button image between a play and stop icon, and start the current tune (the media files are ogg files called 001.ogg, 002.ogg etc):

```
    def clickButtonPlay(self):
            self.buttonPlay+=1
            if self.buttonPlay > 2:
                    self.buttonPlay=1
            self.drawButtonPlay()
            if self.buttonPlay == 1:
                    self.song.stop()
            else:
                    newTune = "tunes/%03d.ogg" %self.tuneNo
                    self.song = pygame.mixer.Sound(newTune)
                    self.song.play()
```

Any ideas what's causing the freeze?

Answer (score 1):

Doh!Should have used pygame.mixer.music, not pygame.mixer.Sound.